# PYTHON - How do I remove a function after it's been executed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, adventure

I'm a bit new to Python programming and I'm trying to create a text-adventure game. I assume I'm using ver 2.7.3?

2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3]

I want to make an inventory system that has a max size. I'm currently using a list for my inventory.

I also want to make some functions a one-time thing; where you can only select one item without choosing another.

Or maybe remove a function *after* it's been executed?

I assume these have to do with classes, but I'm not really advanced on that whole thing. Here is a sample of my code/game. I would like the player to only select one weaponKind.

Since I have a lot of `while True` loops, it's safe to say that the player can go back and choose another `weaponKind`.

```
inventory = ['pen','apple']

import time

while True:

    a2 = raw_input("You begin to download it. The progress bar seems very small, so you decide you'd better do something as time passes. What will you do?" + '\n' + "==> Decide strife specibus" + '\n' + "==> Examine items in (on?) shelf." + '\n' + "==> Doodle on arm" + '\n' + "==> Check inventory" + '\n'+ "==> End game.").upper()
    if a2 == 'DOODLE ON ARM':
        print("You're a natural tattoo artist. Those stick figured dinosaurs rock.")
    if a2 == 'END':
        quit()
    if a2 == 'CHECK INVENTORY':
        print(inventory)
        continue
    if a2 == 'STRFE':
        strife = raw_input("You assume you have to fight monsters in this game. You've heard this is a real-life thing, no VR junk and whatnot. Where will you scour for a weapon? " + '\n' + "==> Scour in the kitchen." + '\n' + "==> Scour in your room. " + '\n' + "==> Scour in the yard.").upper()
        if strife == 'KITCHEN':
            while True:

                a2 = raw_input("You begin to download it. The progress bar seems very small, so you decide you'd better do something as time passes. What will you do?" + '\n' + "==> Decide strife specibus" + '\n' + "==> Examine items in (on?) shelf." + '\n' + "==> Doodle on arm" + '\n' + "==> Check inventory" + '\n'+ "==> End game.").upper()
                if a2 == 'DOODLE ON ARM':
                    print("You're a natural tattoo artist. Those stick figured dinosaurs rock.")
                if a2 == 'END':
                    quit()
                if a2 == 'CHECK INVENTORY':
                    print(inventory)
                    continue
                if a2 == 'STRFE':
                    strife = raw_input("You assume you have to fight monsters in this game. You've heard this is a real-life thing, no VR junk and whatnot. Where will you scour for a weapon? " + '\n' + "==> Scour in the kitchen." + '\n' + "==> Scour in your room. " + '\n' + "==> Scour in the yard." + '\n').upper()
                    if strife == 'KITCHEN':
                        while True:
                            kitchen = raw_input("You lazily go downstairs to the kitchen. There's a plate of *shudder* Betty Crocker cookies on the island. There's the cupboard full of kitchen supplies where your weapon will be. There's also the fridge. The window suggests it's a bit before noon. What will you do?" + '\n' + "==> Eat cookies" + '\n' + "==> Examine cupboard" + '\n' + "==> Open fridge." + '\n' + "==> Exit Kitchen" + '\n').upper()
                            if kitchen == 'EAT COOKIES':
                                print("You hesitate for a moment before grabbing a cookie. Curse that Crocker Corp and its manipulating ways!")
                                def cookie(food):
                                    cookie = food(name = 'BC cookie')
                                inventory.append('BC cookie')
                                print(inventory)
                                time.sleep(3)
                            if kitchen == 'EXAMINE CUPBOARD':
                                while True:
                                specibi = raw_input("There's a mixer, cheese grater, and knife." + '\n' + "> Choose mixer." '\n' + "> Choose knife." + '\n' + "> Choose grater." + '\n').upper()
                                if specibi == 'MIXER':
                                    def mixerKind(strife):
                                        mixerkind = strife(name = "BETTY CRACKER")
                                    inventory.append("BETTY CRACKER")
                                    print(inventory)
                                    time.sleep(3)
                                if specibi == 'KNIFE':
                                    def knifeKind(strife):
                                        knifeKind = strife(name = "BETTY CRACKER")
                                    inventory.append("Kitchen Knife")
                                    print(inventory)
                                    time.sleep(3)
                                    break
                            if kitchen == 'EXIT':
                                break
                    if strife == 'ROOM':
                        pers = raw_input("You find an item related to your interest in archery which is a ")
                        if pers == pers:
                            def originalKind(strife):
                                ogkind = strife(name = pers)
                            inventory.append(str(pers))
                            print(inventory)
```

Comment: Instead of "removing" a function, use `if` statement to check if the function was called before, and call it accordingly inside the `if` body.

Comment: You use the word "function" but don't use any of your own in your code. You should read up on creating functions in Python as it would reduce a lot of the repetition in your code

Comment: It really sounds like you need to look at classes. You can have a player class which has the inventory list and a current_item which points to one of the objects in the inventory. You can also store some state booleans in this class which will allow you to forbid certain actions later using standard `if` statements, which will have the effect of 'removing functions'.

Comment: use some bool variables to control code - ie. `can_choose_weapon =  True`. Other method: at the beginnin set `weapon = None` and later `If weapon is not None: print("you can't get another weapon') else weapon = "knife"`

Answer (score 4):

Here's some code to get your game started, that includes a nice class-based solution to your problem, and cleans up your code so that you don't have a bunch of random logic everywhere that will be illegible to you next week.  I'm sure there will be a gazillion things in here that you don't understand.  Google them all, and change arbitrary lines of code and run it to see what happens.  Enjoy!

```
# This is how I would solve your problem.  
# A room may have various activities that can be performed.... 
# the different types of activity will have different classes
# an activity will include any logic involved in performing the activity
# e.g. an "ItemChoiceActivity" will have a list of possible items,
# the logic of "only one can be chosen" is inherent to the class

class Activity(object):
    pass

class ItemChoiceActivity(Activity):
    '''Implements an activity in which the hero chooses one item from a list'''
    def __init__(self, description, items):
        # pass in a list of Item objects
        self.items = ChoiceList(items)
        self.description = description

    def run(self, hero):
        '''Running an activity gives the hero something to do, 
           then does something to that hero'''
        print self.items
        i = int(raw_input("Choose an item:"))
        hero.pickup_item(self.items[i])
        print hero, " has gained a ", self.items[i]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
    __repr__=__str__

# Rooms are a linked grid, sort of like a linked list
class Room(object):
    '''Implements a Room.  A Room has a textual description, and links to other rooms in the dungeon
    '''
    def __init__(self, description):
        self.description = description #e.g "You enter an empty room... There is a skeleton on the floor.... It stinks in here"
        self.other_room_descriptions = ChoiceList([])
        self.other_rooms = []
        self.activities = ChoiceList([])

    def add_link(self, other_room, link_description):
        ''' Add a link to another room in the dungeon.
            other_room := the other room to link to
            link_description := "north", "south", "secret passage behind the dumpster", etc.
        '''
        # you can iterate through these to describe the directions the hero can go
        self.other_rooms.append(other_room)
        self.other_room_descriptions.append(link_description)

    def add_activity(self, activity):
        self.activities.append(activity)

    def perform_activity(self, i, hero):
        self.activities[i].run(hero)
        self.activities.pop(i)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
    __repr__=__str__

class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, description):
        self.description = description #e.g "staff of healing +2"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
    __repr__ = __str__


class ChoiceList(list):
    '''Just a list of Items, or whatever, but has a nice string repr to display to user'''
    def __str__(self):
        this = ""
        for i in range(len(self)):
            this += str(i) + ": " + str(self[i]) + "\n"
        return this
    __repr__ = __str__


class Hero(object):
    def __init__(self, description):
        MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE = 10
        self.description = description
        self.inventory = ChoiceList([None]*MAX_INVENTORY_SIZE) #Have a static size list to do the standard 'inventory slots' type thing

    def pickup_item(self, item):
        '''Return true if pickup successful, false if no slots available
           this allows the game to handle the situation that the hero
           cannot hold the item... should be handled in the activity'''
        for i in range(len(self.inventory)):
            if self.inventory[i] is None:
                self.inventory[i] = item
                return True
        return False

    def drop_item(self, i):
        '''Drop item at index i... using indices, because that's probably how they will be represented to the user... e.g. user calls "list items" and they get a list 1:staff, 2:wand, etc., then they pick an item by it's index.
        Returns the item dropped'''
        item = self.inventory[i]
        self.inventory[i] = None
        return item

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
    __repr__=__str__


class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, current_room, hero):
        self.current_room = current_room
        self.hero = hero
        self.options = ChoiceList(["Activity", "Move"])

    def main_loop(self):
        print self.current_room.description
        print self.options
        what_to_do = int(raw_input("What to do?"))
        if what_to_do == self.options.index("Activity"):
            print self.current_room.activities
            activity = int(raw_input("Choose an activity:"))
            self.current_room.perform_activity(activity, hero)
        elif what_to_do == self.options.index("Move"):
            print self.current_room.other_room_descriptions
            room = int(raw_input("Choose a room:"))
            self.current_room = self.current_room.other_rooms[room]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    room1 = Room("A really swell room.  Just great, really.")
    room1.add_activity(ItemChoiceActivity("Choose your first weapon", [Item('staff'), Item('pickle')]))
    room2 = Room("A dead end")
    room1.add_link(room2, "a door to the north")
    room2.add_link(room1, "a door to the south")
    hero = Hero("some redneck guy")

    game = Game(room1, hero)
    while True:
        game.main_loop()
```

Comment: NB: There is no error handling here, and everything about this needs to be improved or expanded.  It's just a template to get you off on the right foot as far as code organization, etc.